# Selecting results from table based on combo box data

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Firstly I apologise for my lack of knowledge on SQL.

I currently have two Comboboxes on a form and a list box which looks like the attached image

[TroubleshootPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHVH7.png)

The first combobox references a table with the list of manufacturers and then the second "Model" combobox updates with model numbers which match the first combobox' data

The List box below needs to display data from the "Solutions" Table. ONLY THE "SolutionText" COLUMN

The Manufacturer selected in "cboManfact" has to match the "ManufacturerSolution" in table "Solutions" and then return "SolutionText" if they match. Same for "cboModel" and "ModelSolution".

I dont want the listbox to display any manufacturer or model text, just the "SolutionText" field when a button db_search is pressed.

Thanks to the help of @LiamH, i currently have the following SQL Command on the RowSource of my list box

This can happen either as the user selects options in the comboboxes or when clicking the green search icon

The problem I am having is with the SQL Query. I currently have this below happening when the user clicks the search button

```
SELECT [SolutionText] FROM [Solutions] WHERE solutions.ManufacturerSolution like forms![Troubleshoot]!cboManfact & "*" AND solutions.ModelSolution like forms![Troubleshoot]!cboModel & "*"
```

It displays the SolutionText value in the listbox, but on clicking the "db_search" button, the listbox becomes empty

`Private Sub dbSearch_Click()
     me.listbox.requery
end sub`

Very close to getting this one now, any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed you are using MS-Access, correct me if I am wrong. You may want to consider using `access-vba` tag if this is correct.

There are a few things wrong with your code. Firstly, `docmd.RunSQL` cannot be used on select queries. This (SELECT) is not an action query and this command is reserved for action queries only. e.g. DELETE, UPDATE, ALTER, SELECT...INTO.

When you use multiple where clauses use the word `AND` instead of the ampersand. You don't need to concatenate SQL  strings together. String values that are in a query and related to form values need encapsulating in single quotes, like so:

`"...WHERE NAME='" & Me.name & "'"`

You can use `debug.print strSQL` or `msgbox strSQL` to see how your SQL query reads for any errors.

> So here's what I would do:

Change the rowsource of the listbox to a query:

`SELECT [SolutionText] FROM [Solutions] WHERE solutions.ManufacturerSolution like forms![FORM_NAME]!cboManfact.Column(1) & "*" AND solutions.ModelSolution like forms![FORM_NAME]!cboModel.Column(1) & "*"`

The `like ... & "*"` means that if the combobox is empty it will show all.

You will need some VBA on the `on_click` event, which will be:

```
Private Sub dbSearch_Click()
     me.listbox.requery
end sub
```

The requery will change the listbox items based on the records selected in the combo boxes.

- I don't know what your intention is when using `[Solution Text]`?
- Are you sure you require `column(1)` and not `column(0)`?
- I am not sure what your intention was with `strTableName`?

Comment: You sir are a star. I will adjust the code shortly and get back to you. thank you so much for this :)

Comment: the [SolutionText] is a field within the table that stores troubleshooting steps for that specific model/manufacturer selected. This is the information that i need displayed in the list box. The column(1) stores the actual name of the manufacturer rather than the ID in column(0) which is what i need. strTableName is irelivant and has been removed

Comment: Sorry for asking, but i cannot find "Record Source" on the list box, only control and row sources? Any ideas

Comment: @Batterdburrito sorry, I meant row source.

Comment: Im getting thrown an error with this. It says "Undefined fucntion 'forms!Troubleshoot!cboManfact.Column' in expression

Comment: Maybe try it without the `.column`. It will work based on what the bound column is in the properties of the combobox.

Comment: I think im really close to solving this. Your SQL command seems to want to return all table data into the listbox as it stands. What i need is the Tabledata "SolutionText" displayed in the listbox. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I thought you wanted all the data. See my edit. `SELECT *` will select all fields.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Liam, its really appreciated. I have now got "Testing issue" displayed in the list box, however when i click requery, that value disappears

Comment: For 'simple' queries try creating them in design view and then switch to SQL view and see what access produces. it will often start you in the right direction at least.

Comment: Im switching over to design view to see whats going on. It is working perfectly, but the only issue i have now is that the requery seems to just spaz out and makes the listbox refresh, but not display that refreshed data.

Comment: Does the fact that my Comboboxes get data from a seperate table make a difference at all, thats the only thing i can think of causing the problem (Apologies for not being able to initiate a chat, too new to forums unfortunatley)

Comment: I would have to test it myself, but i'm guessing from what you are saying is when you update the combo boxes the listbox requeries. In which case you would not need the VBA `requery`.

Comment: Hello Liam, just to let you know, issue is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue using the following code:

```
Private Sub dbSearch_Click()

Dim ManfactQuery As String
Dim ModelQuery As String
Dim strSQL As String

ManfactQuery = Me.cboManfact.Column(1)
ModelQuery = Me.cboModel.Column(1)

If Nz(ManfactQuery) = "" Then

strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ModelSolution = '" & ModelQuery & "'"

Else

If Nz(ModelQuery) = "" Then

strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ManufacturerSolution = '" & ManfactQuery & "'"

Else

strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ManufacturerSolution = " & ManfactQuery & " AND [Solutions].ModelSolution = " & ModelQuery & ""

End If

End If

Me.lstSolution.RowSource = strSQL

End Sub
```